# Non Static control inside a static serial datareceived c#

Tags: c#

enter image description hereI am using a "numericUpDown" Tool inside a non static serial datareceived event as follows

```
public void _Serial_Interface_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{   
        decimal _Temp_Value = 2.3;
        //Following statement is used to update the value 
        if(numericUpDown.Minimum < _Temp_Value)
        {
           Invoke(new Action(() => numericUpDown.Value = _Temp_Value));
        }
}
```

How can I define the above condition under static method where "numericUpDown" tool is a non static type?

```
public static void _Serial_Interface_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)    
{

      decimal _Temp_Value = 2.3;      
      ???
}
```

I am using the above functionality in a real time application where Form-1 contains all the port Declaration/Initialize and Form-2 contains serial data received event. When ever the data is available, all the controls in Form-2 will be updated.

Here is the sample example-->

```
enter code here
```

Form-1

namespace _Static_Serial

{

```
public static class _SerialPortCommunicator

{

    private static SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort();

    public static SerialPort SerialPort
    {
        get { return _serialPort; }
        set { _serialPort = value; }
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.PortName = "COM1";
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Form2._Serial_Interface_DataReceived);
        _SerialPortCommunicator.SerialPort.Open();     
    }
}
```

}

Form-2

```
enter code here
```

namespace _Static_Serial

{

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static string indata;
    public static void _Serial_Interface_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        decimal _Temp_Value = Convert.ToDecimal(indata);
       //Error occurs from here onwards
        if (_Temp_Value >= numericUpDown1.Minimum && _Temp_Value <= numericUpDown1.Maximum)
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => numericUpDown1.Value = _Temp_Value));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: The static method needs access to an instance of the class where `_Serial_interface_DataReceived` is defined. The question to ask yourself is, _which_ instance, can there be multiple ones? You need to understand what `static` means to solve this properly.

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? A static method doesn't have access to the instance controls.

Comment: Why do you have one static and one not? Can you make it non static?  If not then I suggest moving it to it's own class.  You could add another event that fires and subscribe to it in your UI code and update that way.

Comment: Hi Michael, How can I convert "numericUpDown" tool into static type?